# Visual State Manager in Windows 10 UWP not applying initial state on page load

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a page with a relative panel to re-organize based on width. However, it doesn't seem to apply any state at load unless the width is > 720px. If I resize the page after it's loaded both states work.

A workaround would be to check the window size on page loaded and manually choose the state, but I believe this should be handled automatically? I have other pages that work, I'm not sure what I'm doing different. Here is a simplified version of my code, I have it set red/blue backgrounds so I can tell if/which state is being applied

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:HighlightConverter x:Key="HighlightConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <gui:MainAppBar x:Name="mainAppBar" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <RelativePanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="ZonesContainer" Margin="12,12,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Zones"/>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ZonesPanel">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="ZonesWrapGrid" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="SourcesContainer" RelativePanel.RightOf="ZonesContainer" Margin="12,12,0,0">
                <GridView x:Name="SourcesPanel" Header="Sources">
                </GridView>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="NetworkServicesContainer" RelativePanel.Below="SourcesContainer" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="SourcesContainer" Margin="12,12,0,0">
                <GridView x:Name="NetworkServicesPanel" Header="Network">
                </GridView>
            </StackPanel>

        </RelativePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ZonesContainer.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ZonesContainer.Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Target="SourcesContainer.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="ZonesContainer" />
                    <Setter Target="SourcesContainer.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith)" Value="ZonesContainer" />
                    <Setter Target="NetworkServicesContainer.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="SourcesContainer" />
                    <Setter Target="ZonesWrapGrid.Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

</Grid>
```

- Update

I've updated the code to show the missing ZonesWrapGrid, it does seem to be  related. The visual states do work on it when I resize the page it will switch the ZonesWrapGrid orientation, just no state set on load.

However, if I remove the ZonesWrapGrid change from the visual state manager the narrow/wide states do correctly apply on load, but of course I lose the orientation change I want.

Comment: `ZonesWrapGrid` element seems to be missing in your XAML and therefore the NarrowState fails to apply. Can you try removing the setter which references `ZonesWrapGrid.Orientation` and run the app again to see if it works?

Comment: @igrali It does seem to be related, I've updated the code to include the grid but it still won't set the state on load even though it does work on resize. Removing it fixes that, but I lose the orientation change I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try just replacing the whole ItemsPanelTemplate? Create both in resources:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VerticalWrapGrid">
    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalWrapGrid">
    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And then swap when needed:

```
<VisualState x:Name="WideState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="ZonesPanel.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalWrapGrid}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="ZonesPanel.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VerticalWrapGrid}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```