# How to change style depending on screen size?

Tags: xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

I would like to change the orientation of a `StackPanel` depending on the screen size.

I've been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33087428/1438809) but haven't got things working yet.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SharedVisualStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="GuidesList.Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultGuidesList}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="GuidesList.Style" Value="{StaticResource NarrowGuidesList}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultGuidesList" TargetType="StackPanel" >
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="NarrowGuidesList" TargetType="StackPanel" >
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel
    x:Name="GuidesList">
    <StackPanel ... />
    <StackPanel ... />
</StackPanel>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, you've put the `VisualStateManager` in a wrong place. To mark it work, you can add the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to the root element of your page.

> Control authors or app developers add [VisualStateGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstategroup.aspx) object elements to the **root element** of a control template definition in XAML, using the [VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.visualstategroups.aspx) attached property.

For more info, please see [VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.visualstategroups.aspx).

So I changed your code like following:

```
<Page x:Class="UWP.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:UWP"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultGuidesList" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="NarrowGuidesList" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SharedVisualStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="GuidesList.Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultGuidesList}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="GuidesList.Style" Value="{StaticResource NarrowGuidesList}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <StackPanel x:Name="GuidesList">
            <StackPanel Width="400"
                        Height="200"
                        Background="Red" />
            <StackPanel Width="400"
                        Height="200"
                        Background="Blue" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And it works well.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in the old good manner.
Add in XAML two visual states:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="GuidesList">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="HorLayout">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GuidesList" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Orientation">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Horizontal"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VertLayout">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GuidesList" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Orientation">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Vertical"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   .....
```

And handle page size changed event:

```
  private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width < 700)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VertLayout", true);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "HorLayout", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good to know how to handle this programmatically too, cheers!